# How to set border color of TickLabels excel chart c#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

i am developing a chart programmatically using c# and excel interop dll.
i have to set the border color of TickLabels in excel chart. here is my screen shot where i am point the area which border color need to be set programmatically. i tried lot & search google but found no clue. so please see my pic & code and help me to achieve my goal.

[image]

### here is my full code

```
public ChartData PrepareExcel()
        {
            bool flag = false;
            int rowindex = 3;
            if (oData != null)
            {
                if (oData.Tables.Count > 0)
                {

                    if (oData.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Excel.Application xlApp;
                        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet1;
                        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet2;
                        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheetChart;
                        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

                        try
                        {
                            xlWorkSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                            xlWorkSheet1.Name = "Detail Data";

                            xlWorkSheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
                            xlWorkSheet2.Name = "Summary Data";

                            xlWorkSheetChart = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(3);
                            xlWorkSheetChart.Name = "Chart";


                            // for first sheet start
                            xlWorkSheet1.Cells[1, 1] = "Daily Finished Jobs History Detail Report From " +
                                DateTime.ParseExact(this.startdate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +" To " +
                                DateTime.ParseExact(this.enddate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                            xlWorkSheet1.get_Range("A1", "Y1").Merge(true);
                            xlWorkSheet1.get_Range("A1", "Y1").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                            xlWorkSheet1.get_Range("A1", "Y1").Font.Bold = true;
                            xlWorkSheet1.get_Range("A1", "Y1").Font.Size = 14;
                            xlWorkSheet1.get_Range("A3", "Y3").Font.Bold = true;

                            for (int x = 0; x <= oData.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; x++)
                            {
                                xlWorkSheet1.Cells[3, x + 1] = oData.Tables[0].Columns[x].ColumnName.ToString();
                                xlWorkSheet1.Columns[x + 1].AutoFit();
                                //xlWorkSheet1.Columns[x + 1].Font.Bold = true;
                            }


                            for (int x = 0; x <= oData.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; x++)
                            {
                                int row= rowindex + (x + 1);
                                for (int y = 0; y <= oData.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; y++)
                                {
                                    xlWorkSheet1.Cells[row, y + 1] = oData.Tables[0].Rows[x][y].ToString();
                                    xlWorkSheet1.Columns[1].AutoFit();
                                }
                            }

                            // for first sheet end

                            // for second sheet start

                            xlWorkSheet2.Cells[1, 1] = "Daily Finished Jobs History Summary Report From " +
                            DateTime.ParseExact(this.startdate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " To " +
                            DateTime.ParseExact(this.enddate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                            xlWorkSheet2.get_Range("A1", "I1").Merge(true);
                            xlWorkSheet2.get_Range("A1", "I1").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                            xlWorkSheet2.get_Range("A1", "I1").Font.Bold = true;
                            xlWorkSheet2.get_Range("A1", "I1").Font.Size = 14;
                            xlWorkSheet2.get_Range("A3", "I3").Font.Bold = true;

                            for (int x = 0; x <= oData.Tables[1].Columns.Count - 1; x++)
                            {
                                xlWorkSheet2.Cells[3, x + 1] = oData.Tables[1].Columns[x].ColumnName.ToString();
                                xlWorkSheet2.Columns[x + 1].AutoFit();
                            }

                            for (int x = 0; x <= oData.Tables[1].Rows.Count - 1; x++)
                            {
                                int row = rowindex + (x + 1);
                                for (int y = 0; y <= oData.Tables[1].Columns.Count - 1; y++)
                                {
                                    xlWorkSheet2.Cells[row, y + 1] = oData.Tables[1].Rows[x][y].ToString();
                                    xlWorkSheet2.Columns[1].AutoFit();
                                }
                                flag = true;
                            }

                            //for second sheet end

                            // chart start

                            if (flag)
                            {
                                Excel.SeriesCollection seriesCollection;
                                Excel.Series series1, series2, series3;

                                Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheetChart.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
                                Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 20, 900, 520);
                                Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
                                chartPage.HasTitle = true;
                                chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "Daily Job History Chart  From " +
                                DateTime.ParseExact(this.startdate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " To " +
                                DateTime.ParseExact(this.enddate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                                chartPage.Legend.Position = XlLegendPosition.xlLegendPositionBottom;

                                seriesCollection = (Excel.SeriesCollection)chartPage.SeriesCollection(Type.Missing);
                                series1 = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
                                series2 = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
                                series3 = seriesCollection.NewSeries();

                                series1.Name = "='Summary Data'!$B$3";
                                series1.Values = "='Summary Data'!$B$4:$B$" + (5+ oData.Tables[1].Rows.Count);
                                series1.ChartType = XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
                                series1.AxisGroup = XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary;

                                series2.Name = "='Summary Data'!$C$3";
                                series2.XValues = "='Summary Data'!$A$4:$A$" + (5 + oData.Tables[1].Rows.Count);
                                series2.Values = "='Summary Data'!$C$4:$C$" + (5 + oData.Tables[1].Rows.Count);
                                series2.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLineMarkers;


                                series3.Name = "='Summary Data'!$D$3";
                                series3.Values = "='Summary Data'!$D$4:$D$" + (5 + oData.Tables[1].Rows.Count);
                                series3.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLineMarkers;
                                series3.AxisGroup = XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary;

                                Axis axis;
                                axis = (Axis)chartPage.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
                                axis.HasTitle = true;
                                axis.AxisTitle.Text = "Percentage/Hour";
                                axis.AxisTitle.Font.Color = Color.Blue;
                                axis.Border.Color = Color.Transparent;
                                axis.HasMajorGridlines = false;
                                axis.HasMinorGridlines = false;

                                axis = (Axis)chartPage.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary);
                                axis.HasTitle = true;
                                axis.AxisTitle.Text = "Total Jobs completed";
                                axis.AxisTitle.Font.Color = Color.Blue;
                                axis.HasMajorGridlines = true;
                                axis.HasMinorGridlines = false;

                                axis = (Excel.Axis)chartPage.Axes(XlAxisType.xlCategory);
                                axis.MajorTickMark = XlTickMark.xlTickMarkNone;
                                axis.HasMajorGridlines = true;

                                chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory).Select();
                                chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory).TickLabels.Orientation = 35;
                            }
                            // chart end
                            string strpath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\DailyFinishedJobHistoryReport_"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+".xls";

                            if (File.Exists(strpath))
                            {
                                File.Delete(strpath);
                            }

                            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(strpath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
                            xlWorkBook = null;
                            xlApp.Quit();
                            xlApp = null;
                            GC.Collect();
                            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return this;
        }
```

please see my **arrow area where date is showing**. i want to change the border color of that area. guide me. thanks

### UPDATE

[image]

see this screen shot. basically i want to change the border color of that area to transparent but i am not getting any clue that where i need to add the code. if still i am not clear then please let me know. thanks

Comment: It is not too clear what you mean with border color of this area. Do you mean surrounding all this text with a rectangle of certain color? Can you please perform the exact modification you want manually in Excel and post here the snapshot?

Comment: PS: using GC is rarely a good idea, better let C# take care of this by its own.

Comment: i update my question. please see the update area at bottom. thanks

Comment: Thanks. But I am still not understanding what you want. Your new pic does not contain any border; this is what you want? Removing all the borders (including the upper horizontal line with small vertical bits)?

Comment: yes he is trying to know how to remove upper horizontal line with small vertical bits. if u know how to do it then please give him detail instruction to edit his code to have the effect. thanks

Comment: @mou OK, If you are so sure that this what he wants, I will try to help him tomorrow (did something on these lines some time ago which should work). Bear in mind that you have to write @ + nick if it isn't your question/answer; I have seen your message now by pure chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assuming that you want what I have suggested via comments and without coming into too much detail in the rest of the code (just quick suggestion: better delete the `GC` part); this is what you are after:

```
axis = (Axis)chartPage.Axes(XlAxisType.xlCategory);
axis.MajorTickMark = XlTickMark.xlTickMarkNone;
axis.Format.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
```

This code refers to the X axis: the second line removes the major ticks (small vertical lines shown in your picture) and the third line the horizontal line. Regarding this second correction, bear in mind that you have `.HasMajorGridlines = true;` on the X axis and thus you will continue seeing a horizontal line, the one from the major gridlines (this one cannot be deleted unless writing `.HasMajorGridlines = false;` for the X axis).

NOTE: as highlighted by the OP via comments, the last line of the code above refers to a property (`Format`) which does not exist in Office 2003. This code should work fine with Office 2010 and newer versions.

Comment: this line is giving problem....axis.Format.Line.Visible there is no axis.format available.i am using excel interop dll version 1.5.0.0 is there any way out available. thanks for answer.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry but I only have Office 2010 (14.0 Object Library; 1.7 Type library). I guess that you have Office 2003; sorry cannot test your conditions. You should indicate your Office version (mainly for old versions; that is, anything before 2007). Look through the axis properties for something on these lines (line's format); there should be an equivalent somewhere.

Comment: @Thomas bear in mind that the first line (`axis.MajorTickMark = XlTickMark.xlTickMarkNone;`) removes already the small vertical lines; and that `axis.Format.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;` does not have a real effect if `.HasMajorGridlines = true;` for the given axis (what is the case in your code). For the time being, you can just use the first two lines of the aforementioned code and ignore the last one: check if this delivers what you are looking for.